# C++ program hangs when setting variable

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program in C++ and I have input with bounds and a grid for example:

```
4 4
SOUI
1234
WER5
0234
```

I'm using the following loop to read input

```
    int N, M, startR = 0, startC = 0;
    string matrix[105][105], instr;

    cin >> N >> M;

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        cin >> instr;
        for(int j = 0; j < M; j++){
            matrix[i][j] = instr[j];
            if(matrix[i][j] == "B"){
                startR = i;
                startC = j;
            }
        }
    }
```

If I use this code, the program will ask for more input and won't run no matter what I give it. This means the code after this input loop is never used. However, if I remove the setting of variables, the program runs fine. For example:

```
    int N, M, startR = 0, startC = 0;
    string matrix[105][105], instr;

    cin >> N >> M;

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        cin >> instr;
        for(int j = 0; j < M; j++){
            matrix[i][j] = instr[j];
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure why this is happening as all I'm doing is setting some other variables. I need the information about where the variable B is found. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: It seems that you need a matrix of chars, not strings.

Comment: `matrix[i][j] = instr[j];` assigns a `char` to a `string`. I suspect Bob is correct. I see no need for `string` - anything here.

Comment: You are right that it should be a char but it doesn't solve the problem of continuously reading from the input stream.

Comment: Without a [mre], which would include the actual input data, it's unlikely that anyone will be able to help you.

Comment: Embedding your code inside a simple `main()` works fine on MSVC (with your sample input). However, there is this warning: **Function uses '352856' bytes of stack:  exceeds /analyze:stacksize '16384'.  Consider moving some data to heap.**

Comment: @SamVarshavchik putting this code inside a main function should be a complete program.

Comment: @AdrianMole is it possible this is a compiler problem?

Comment: @Jimmy What compiler/platform are you on? Could be stack corruption if it's a smallish memory model?

Comment: It *should*, with the right includes, but your milage may vary.

Comment: Also, with the input data you provide, the `if(matrix[i][j] == "B"){` block is never executed, anyway!

Comment: I made a mistake in this post as the problem was in a loop in the code afterwards. I thought I had replicated this using a separate test file but I was wrong, that's my bad. My takeaway from this was that the code right behind cin behaves weird if code further down the line is an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this as the problem lied in the code after the loop. The problem was misleading as it seemed like cin was taking more input but it was actually the infinite loop later. I tried to first debug using print statements immediately after the cin statement to see what was being taken in but those weren't run which is what threw me off. My takeaway is to look at the program completely and use a full debugger.